# Set an edittext in a fragment after getting the result from a scanning activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-camera

I have a CaptureActivity to scan barcodes with mobile camera.
I'm trying to launch this activity from a fragment, and let the fragment waiting for the activity to complete the scanning of a barcode. With the result of the scanning I'd like to fill an edittext inside the parent fragment. How to can I do that?

Comment: Send a broadcast intent in the parent Activity and register a broadcast receiver in your Fragment holding the EditText.

Comment: please add some codes

Comment: You can use interface to communicate between Activity and Fragment

Answer (score 1):

You can use `startActivityForResult` method:

***Parent activity:***

```java
final int BARCODE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1

private void startBarcodeScannerActivityForResult() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BarcodeActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, BARCODE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == BARCODE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String barcode = data.getStringExtra("barcode");
        }
    }
}
```

***Barcode activity***

```java
private void handleDecodeInternally(Result rawResult, ResultHandler resultHandler, Bitmap barcode) {
    String barcode = resultHandler.getDisplayContents().toString();
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("barcode",barcode);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    finish();
 }
```

More details about `startActivityForResult` : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity